# Inconsistent sample sizes between sample_frac() and slice_sample()

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I noticed that i get a different amount of samples when working with `sample_frac()` and `slice_sample()`. I'm following an older tutorial and I started replacing `sample_frac()` with `slice_sample(prop = )` and I get a different amount of rows.

```
as_tibble(volcano) %>% 
  group_by(V1) %>% 
  sample_frac(0.5)
# output: 44 * 61 sized tbl

as_tibble(volcano) %>% 
  group_by(V1) %>% 
  slice_sample(prop = 0.5)
# output: 39 * 61 sized tbl
```

While I understand that in smaller datasets these function have to round, I would like to know if one function is more accurate than another. Especially when working with many groups each sized under ~15 rows, the sample size is very different. Its off-putting.

the `sample_frac()` documentation states:

> sample_n() and sample_frac() have been superseded in favour of slice_sample().

Which makes it even weirder if they dont behave  the same.

Comment: Is it that `sample_frac` does not take the `group_by` into account?

Comment: `sample_frac` uses `round`, `slice_sample` uses `floor`. When you have 27 groups each with between 2-7 rows, the round/floor differences will accumulate. In this case, there are five groups with an odd number of rows.

Comment: @Maël it does take `group_by` into considereation

Comment: @r2evans seems like thats it! is there a way to use `round` with `slice_sample` or vice versa?

Comment: I'd have to dig through dplyr's github issue history, but I wouldn't be surprised that at some point the use of `round` was considered a mistake and switching to `floor` was an improvement. Using `round` means that if you specify 0.5 you can get sample with more than half the size, so ensuring "at most" that proportion is probably desirable.

Comment: notRelevant: sure ... submit a PR, or just clone the repo, patch the source, and install from local ... perhaps not what you wanted to hear. @joran, that sounds consistent with other changes they've made in the past. Frankly I wish they documented the _change_, though the docs do say `‘prop’ will be rounded towards zero to generate an integer number of rows`.

Comment: As it looks like there is no toggle for it in the function. Can somebody answer it so i can mark it as the "solution"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BLUF: `sample_frac` uses `round` whereas `slice_sample` uses `floor`. Since `volcano` has five groups with an odd number of rows, those groups have one fewer rows in the post-sampling, resulting in a 5-row difference.

`sample_frac` (superseded), from [`5735f03`](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/blob/5735f0399ad7a89bbaeec143e1c639d148d80c79/R/sample.R#L109-L123), note the use of `round`:

```r
sample_frac.data.frame <- function(tbl, size = 1, replace = FALSE,
                                   weight = NULL, .env = NULL, ...) {
  if (!is_null(.env)) {
    inform("`.env` is deprecated and no longer has any effect")
  }

  size <- enquo(size)
  weight <- enquo(weight)

  dplyr_local_error_call()
  slice(tbl, local({
    size <- round(n() * check_frac(!!size, replace = replace))
    sample.int(n(), size, replace = replace, prob = !!weight)
  }))
}
```

`slice_sample` (current), also as of [`5735f03`](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/blob/5735f0399ad7a89bbaeec143e1c639d148d80c79/R/slice.R#LL256-L269):

```r
slice_sample.data.frame <- function(.data, ..., n, prop, weight_by = NULL, replace = FALSE) {
  size <- get_slice_size(n = n, prop = prop, allow_outsize = replace)

  dplyr_local_error_call()
  slice(.data, local({
    weight_by <- {{ weight_by }}

    n <- dplyr::n()
    if (!is.null(weight_by)) {
      weight_by <- vec_assert(weight_by, size = n, arg = "weight_by")
    }
    sample_int(n, size(n), replace = replace, wt = weight_by)
  }))
}
```

and its helper function (same file), note the use of `floor` here:

```r
get_slice_size <- function(n, prop, allow_outsize = FALSE, error_call = caller_env()) {
  slice_input <- check_slice_n_prop(n, prop, error_call = error_call)

  if (slice_input$type == "n") {
    if (slice_input$n >= 0) {
      function(n) clamp(0, floor(slice_input$n), if (allow_outsize) Inf else n)
    } else {
      function(n) clamp(0, ceiling(n + slice_input$n), n)
    }
  } else if (slice_input$type == "prop") {
    if (slice_input$prop >= 0) {
      function(n) clamp(0, floor(slice_input$prop * n), if (allow_outsize) Inf else n)
    } else {
      function(n) clamp(0, ceiling(n + slice_input$prop * n), n)
    }
  }
}
```

Side note: the allowance of negative `prop` produces a different result, though `slice_sample(prop=-0.5)` returns 48 instead of 44 from `sample_frac`.